# Programmatically check a website's SSL certificate for expiration

Tags: python, ruby, ssl, https, tdd

How can this be done with a common scripting language such as python, ruby, or bash? I.e., I'd like to write a script that will either return a "valid" or "expired" result. It looks like the `openssl` program with the `s_client` option may be able to do this, or return a result that can be checked.

Ah hah: by default, curl will verify a website's certificate. It will return a message like this if it's expired:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Not very specific, but it's clear that there's a cert failure. It links to this page for info: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the [ruby bindings for libcurl](https://github.com/taf2/curb) can do a very general test:

```
$ gem install curb
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'curl'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Curl.get('https://site-with-expired-cert.com')
Curl::Err::SSLCACertificateError: Curl::Err::SSLCACertificateError
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:62:in `perform'
[3] pry(main)> Curl.get('https://github.com')
=> #<Curl::Easy https://github.com>
```